# Why does my Excel formula only take one value from the range?

Tags: excel, sum, formula

I'm trying to add together the numbers before a division (for example **5**/10 and **7**/10 would give me 12) in a range using the code `=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(LEFT(E14:E20,1)+0),LEFT(E14:E20,FIND("/",E14:E20)-1)))`
but even though I specify a range (E14:E20) it only takes one number from that range. Specifically it takes the number that is on the same row as the formula.

[image]

Why does this code not function? Why does it only take the number on the same row?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your fractions are entered as text, with a minor modification, so that `value_if_true` gets converted to a number (note the `0+` I added), it works fine here

Try:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(LEFT(E14:E20,1)+0),0+LEFT(E14:E20,FIND("/",E14:E20)-1)))
```

*In some earlier versions of Excel, you may need to "confirm" this **array-formula** it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar*

[image]